# Calling gcc from python script gives me 'Undefined symbols: "_main"

Tags: python, c, gcc, code-generation

I am trying to write a code generator script in Python, that generates a C-source file, compiles it and runs it. However, I am having trouble calling gcc from my script.

A simple hello world example:

```
import subprocess  

basename = "CodeGenTest";  
execname = basename;  
srcname = basename + ".c";  

codeList = [];  
codeList.append("#include <stdio.h>");  
codeList.append("int main(int argc, char *argv[])\n{");  
codeList.append("printf(\"Hello world.\\n\");");  
codeList.append("}");  

# Convert codelist to string.  
codeList.append("");  
codeString = "\n".join(codeList);  

# Print code to output source file  
outfile=open(srcname,'w');  
outfile.write(codeString);  
outfile.close;  

print "Compile.";  
cmd = ["gcc", "-O2", srcname, "-o", execname];  
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd);  
p.wait();  

subprocess.call(["./"+execname]);
```

If I run this script, I get the following error output

```
Compile.
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I do the exact same thing in the python interpreter shell, it works fine. I can also compile the code without problems directly in the shell.

I have tried various variants, using subprocess.Popen(), subprocess.call(), with and without all possible combinations of arguments that I can think of, still the same problem.

Anyone has any idea what might be my problem here?

Comment: This sounds like a stripped-down example of a horribly bad idea. You cannot write a compiler without using a (non-string!) internal representation (AST = **abstract** syntax **tree**), and likewise you can't generate nontrivial source code only with strings.

Comment: The code generator is going to generate, compile and run a very specific piece of code and evaluate it for various optimization parameters (i.e. an auto tuner), and in the end spit out the best version of the code, runtime-wise. I am perfectly aware of the need for higher level abstractions of the code, but at some point I need to generate and compile the code, which this post is a simple example of.

Answer (score 6):

Change this

```
outfile.close;
```

to this:

```
outfile.close()
```

You're not actually closing the file, so Python isn't flushing its buffers, so all that's in the source file is an empty file.  When gcc compiles an empty file, it complains that there's no `main` function to serve as the program's entry point.

I'd also suggest that you check that `p.returncode` is 0 to ensure that gcc succeeded before trying to execute the (possibly non-existant) output binary.

Also there's no need to end each statement with a semicolon.  You only need a semicolon if you have multiple statements per line, in which case you need them in between statements.  End-of-line servers as a statement terminator when not preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I've been staring my eyes blind on this for hours, and I didn't see it (why didn't Python give me an error message?). The semicolons are just an automatic habit since I mostly write C/C++ code.

Comment: @Magnus: Because it's not an error. Not *necessarily*. Yes, left alone it's propably a mistake, but I don't want to miss first-class functions and only warning when it is discarded requires way more static analysis than CPython does. Also, I rarely run into this myself... maybe just a matter of habit.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling `outfile.close`; it should be `outfile.close()`. Good chance the source is still stuck in a buffer somewhere, and GCC doesn't see it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the problem by using a with-block to manage the file:

```
with file(srcname, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(codeString)
```

Also please note that semicolons are not required in Python unless you are writing multiple statements on the same line.